# Using Base Entity Context for code first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

**TLDR:** Why is Entity Framework appending extra path to the end of my datasource? What do I need to do in order to use this framework? Is there another way to handle this?

I am writing a basic SQL Server CE winforms program to store some data. I originally had 1 context to be used to interact with 1 class. Now, I wish to add another class, and so I refactored out a base context that the original context could be derived from. I have the code running, although I can't create any database with it.

I take a path in from the user to the database and set the |DataDirectory|, which I use for the data source.

```
<add name="MonsterContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|; Persist Security Info=False"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

I intend for the data source to look like

```
C:Path\To\DatabaseFile.sdf
```

but it comes out as

```
C:\Path\To\DatabaseFile.sdf\Namespace.BaseContext`1[Namespace.ModelClass].sdf ]"}
```

I think this path demonstrates that it is building its own source based on EF defaults.

My base Context is:

```
public class EntityContext<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public EntityContext()
        : base("name=MonsterContext")
    {
    }

    public EntityContext(string tableName)
    {
        this.TableName = tableName;
    }

    public DbSet<T> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

And My Derived Context is:

```
public class MonsterReader : Reader<Monster>
{
    private List<Monster> monsters;

    public List<Monster> Monsters
    {
        get
        {
            if (monsters == null)
            {
                monsters = ReadAll();
            }
            return monsters;
        }
        private set { monsters = value; }
    }

    public MonsterReader(string file)
        : base(file)
    { }

    public MonsterReader(Stream reader)
        : base(reader)
    { }

    public void CreateMonsterDatabase(IEnumerable<Monster> monsters)
    {
        CreateDatabase(monsters, TableName);
    }

    private string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem, it was a simple omission from the base context.

In the Base Entity Context, the first constructor is:

```
public EntityContext()
    : base("name=MonsterContext")
{
}
```

However, the constructor that takes a table name is

```
public EntityContext(string tableName)
{
    this.TableName = tableName;
}
```

which is missing the `: base("name=MonsterContext")`

This call is necessary if you want to call a specific connection string from the app.config.
In this case, the connection string you want to call is "Monster Context". Without specifying which context, Entity Framework defaults using SQL Server CE to

```
|DataDirectory|\Namespace.NameofContext.sdf
```